trying to apply a bs4-approach to wikipedia-page: results do not store in a df
due to the fact that scraping on Wikipedia is a very very common technique - where we can use an appropiate approach to work with many many different jobs - i did have some issues with getting back the results - and store it into a df
well - as a example for a very common Wikipedia-bs4 job - we can take this one:
on this page we have more than 600 results - in sub-pages:
url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Genossenschaftsbanken_in_Deutschland"
so to do a first experimental script i follow like so : first i scrape the table from the Wikipedia page and afterwards i convert it into a Pandas DataFrame.
therefore i first install necessary packages: Make sure you have requests, beautifulsoup4, and pandas installed. You can install them using pip if you haven't already:
pip install requests beautifulsoup4 pandas

and then i follow like so : first i scrape the table from the Wikipedia page and afterwards i convert it into a Pandas DataFrame.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# URL of the Wikipedia page
url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Genossenschaftsbanken_in_Deutschland"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content of the page with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find the first table in the page
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})

# Initialize an empty list to store the data
data = []

# Iterate over the rows of the table
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    # Get the columns in each row
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    # If there are columns in the row, get the text from each column and store it in the data list
    if cols:
        data.append([col.get_text(strip=True) for col in cols])

# Convert the data list to a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Bank Name", "Location", "Website"])

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

# Optionally, save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('genossenschaftsbanken.csv', index=False)

see what i have got back:
3 s

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

# Optionally, save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('genossenschaftsbanken.csv', index=False)

  Bank Name                                           Location  \
0      BWGV  Baden-Württembergischer Genossenschaftsverband...   
1       GVB                 Genossenschaftsverband Bayerne. V.   
2        GV                                   Genoverbande. V.   
3      GVWE              Genossenschaftsverband Weser-Emse. V.   
4       FGV                Freier Genossenschaftsverband e. V.   
5       PDG     PDG Genossenschaftlicher Prüfungsverband e. V.   
6                              Verband der Sparda-Banken e. V.   
7                                 Verband der PSD Banken e. V.   

             Website  
0          Karlsruhe  
1            München  
2  Frankfurt am Main  
3          Oldenburg  
4         Düsseldorf  
5             Erfurt  
6  Frankfurt am Main  
7               Bonn

well i guess that i have to re-write the end of the script...
update: what is aimed - is to  get the data out of the block see for an example:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abtsgm%C3%BCnder_Bank


What is the actual question? You're getting your df, no? Where is the problem? Though you can also just use pd.read_html(url)[0] to get the same table with minimal effort.

what are you expecting your df to look like?

thanks for the reply_  well update: what is aimed - is to get the data out of the block see for an example that i have added in the update - to the orginal post.
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abtsgm%C3%BCnder_Bank

note : i am willing to fetch the page of the block - see the example that i have added above.
well - this is a pretty common task for Wikipedia-scraping. And i am pulling my hair that i do not find the key to this solution... to get the data that is stored in the block - to a csv-based output...

What does "get the data out of the block" mean?

I think you need to better explain the issue here as it's not clear. What I THINK you are trying to do is get the links from that original page, then go to each of those pages to get the data of that example you provided. I'll give you this bit here to work off of. Again I'm not sure what you are exactly wanting.
Code:
import pandas as pd

# URL of the Wikipedia page
url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Genossenschaftsbanken_in_Deutschland"
table = pd.read_html(url, extract_links='all')[1]
base_url = 'https://de.wikipedia.org'
table = table.apply(lambda col: [v[0] if v[1] is None else f'{base_url}{v[1]}' for v in  col])


links = list(table.iloc[:,0])

for link in links:
    print('\n',link)
    try:
        df = pd.read_html(link)[0]
        print(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

